# how to accelerate ssl

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

When I invoke an API which was provider by our partner in India ,It always spend to many time. Our service is in Beijing and the partner web server is in India. We use SSL/TLS secure connection.

I use package capture tool **wireShark** to observe the process. And I found SSL/TLS spends the most time.

[image]

How can I slove this problem?
Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell. It looks like there's a 2.5 second delay after packet 2169 after which a retransmission occurs and your client responds. Is this a repeating phenomenon? You should take a few captures and determine if the pattern is the same each time. Could simply be down to link-quality ...

Comment: @robert ,Yes, It always occurs retransmission , sometimes it takes 300 millisecond, but sometimes it takes few seconds.